# No recibo el correo, pero recibo una respuesta del servidor (214 2.0.0 https://www.google.com/search?btnI&q=RFC+5321...)

Tags: c++, email

Esta es una clase encargada de enviar un email simple, pero tengo un problema y es que no recibo el correo electrónico...... no es la seguridad de mi correo, intente enviar el correo a un correo para spam y tampoco lo recibió.

El mensaje que recibo es:

> 214 2.0.0  https://www.google.com/search?btnI&q=RFC+5321
> hi11-20020a17090b30cb00b00277371fd346sm2525727pjb.30 - gsmtp
> Correo electrónico enviado con éxito.

Dependencias: `Libcurl`.

El mensaje "Correo electrónico enviado con éxito" proviene del codigo.

Asi llamo a la clase (main):

```
    MailServer mailServer;
    std::string to = "cryptosignalsm.e.a@gmail.com";
    std::string subject = "wena shoro";
    std::string message = "Cuerpo del correo electrónico.";

    mailServer.SendEmail(to, subject, message);
```

Este es el código de la clase:

```
public:
    void SendEmail(const std::string& to, const std::string& subject, const std::string& message) {
        m_to = to;
        m_subject = subject;
        m_message = message;

        // Inicialización de libcurl
        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
        curl = curl_easy_init();

        // Configuración de la URL del servidor SMTP de Gmail
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465");

        // Deshabilitar verificación SSL temporalmente (¡no recomendado para producción!)
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

        // Configuración de la autenticación
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "TU_EMAIL");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "TU_CONTRASEÑA_ESPECIAL_PARA_APPS");

        // Configuración del remitente y destinatario
        struct curl_slist* recipients = NULL;
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, m_to.c_str());
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);

        // Configuración del mensaje
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, ReadCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, this);

        // Enviar el mensaje
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        } else {
            printf("Correo electrónico enviado con éxito.\n");
        }

        // Limpieza y liberación de recursos
        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup();
    }

private:
    CURL* curl;
    std::string m_to;
    std::string m_subject;
    std::string m_message;

    static size_t ReadCallback(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) {
        MailServer* self = static_cast<MailServer*>(userp);
        if (self->m_message.empty()) {
            return 0;
        }

        size_t len = std::min(size * nmemb, self->m_message.size());
        memcpy(ptr, self->m_message.c_str(), len);
        self->m_message = self->m_message.substr(len);

        return len;
    }
};
```

Comment: En lugar de mostrar el error "Correo electrónico enviado con éxito.\n" te sugiero mostrar el resultado de curl, para ver la página, ya que en ella estará el error real. El problema es que entras en la parte del if de todo ok porque el resultado de curl es correcto, pero esa página mostrará un error en realidad.

Comment: Respuesta de la página web:
_214 2.0.0  https://www.google.com/search?btnI&q=RFC+5321 o1-20020a170902d4c100b001b392bf9192sm2441197plg.145 - gsmtp_

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero en tu función faltan muchas cosas para poder enviar un correo, como el from por ejemplo, el helo y algunas otras cosas, mira por ejemplo esta otra función: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html